# What genetic biomarkers are the best place to obtain histopathological images for the purpose of cancer classification?

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, histopathology

I am doing a science-fair project and wanted to know where I could obtain the best possible histopathological images of both non-cancerous and cancerous subjects. I would require roughly more than ~50k images.

Comment: It sounds like you might be doing some form of image analysis for features followed by statistical analysis, with needs for a dataset that size. I would suggest looking at what others have done in the past and see if you can find their datasets. For example, [here is a recent review](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2021.754641/full). One possible resource might be [here](https://www.cancerimagingarchive.net/histopathology-imaging-on-tcia/). All of this would show up in a google search. If those don't answer your question, feel free to edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Do you mean biomarkers (e.g. proteins such as CEA or other biologic substances whose expression/appearance or lack thereof correlates with cancer) or databases? I think some clarification to your question could help others answer your question. Also, for 50k+ images, I think it is likely that you need to partner with an institution to obtain this data.

Comment: Maximillian, are you sure the resources of cancer imaging archives that you sent me is trustable? Because it is asking for access to transfer files to and from my computer. Otherwise, these are some really good images for my project and will most likely help me succeed.

Comment: The grammar in the title of the question here doesn't make sense to me. "Genetic biomarkers" are not a place. Additionally, "best" depends on some criteria, which are not specified here.

Comment: Additionally: At what cancer are you looking? Biomarkers differ widely and are often not very good. Reliable biomarkers for certain cancers are a "one million dollar" question.